# Raspberry Pi change path variable in profile not working

Tags: path, debian

I would like to make my python script available to wherever I am. my python script is in /usr/share/pyshared/compteur so I have added the command to my .profile file `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/pyshared/compteur`

I rebooted my raspberry but if I try `python compteur.py`, it says it doesn't find the file.

How can I make this work?

ls -l folder gives

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 pi users 1273 Nov 30 15:26 camera.py
-rwxr--r-- 1 pi users  842 Nov 30 15:26 upload.py
```

head gives

```
head /usr/share/pyshared/compteur/camera.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Camera version 0.1

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from subprocess import call
import time
import ConfigParser

def main():
```

Comment: compteur.py is in the folder /usr/share/pyshared/compteur/ and if I execute it from that folder, it works fine. But if I go in my home folder (/home/pi/) and I do python compteur.py, it doesn't find the file even though echo $PATH gives me the path /usr/share/pyshared/compteur/

Comment: can you edit your question and add `ls -l /usr/share/pyshared/compteur` and `head /usr/share/pyshared/compteur/compteur.py`?

Comment: you shoud run `compteur.py` directly instead of using `python compteur.py`

Comment: I have tried ./compteur.py or ./compteur from anywhere, even in the right folder and it says: : No such file or directory

Comment: try `compteur.py` instead of `./compteur.py`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you did this but just for the files: did you execute  `echo $PATH` and check if your env setting succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by adding the command to your .bashrc (or .zshrc) file.

```sh
source $HOME/.profile
```

And restart your terminal. And all path setting in ~/.profile can work normally.